# How do you represent small molecules in SBOL?

Tags: sbol

In SBOL, how do you represent small molecules like arabinose or chloramphenicol?

There's a type for saying a component is a small molecule, but they don't really have sequences like DNA or proteins do, so what's the recommended way to provide information about it other than just the name?